# How to turn on Android VPN tunnel from source code?

Tags: android, shell, vpn, android-service

I have implemented an Android application which connects to its application server via a VPN tunnel. Thats fine.
However I want that the application turn on the Android VPN service itself ,rather than I am turning on the VPN on Android manually. 
Is it possible to turn on this from java source code, like

```
// TO DO
if (something) {
VPN ON
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Currently it's not possible to do that. Event with the [latest classes in Android 4.0](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/VpnService.html), *User action is required to create a VPN connection*. It's considered a security issue to be able progrmmatically to establish vpn connection (e.g. without the user to notice).

Comment: and prepare(Context) and establish()is used to initiate the VPN, yes as you said these methods will be called when user pressed a button, what is that button? can it not be accessed from application and like when it is needed can we pretend like user pressed the button?

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to turn off the VPN from Java source code, unless the device is rooted, then there some hacks around. (so I have been told being an Android developer for a major software company) It is almost possible to do but it will take writing something in Native Code. There are some companies that are currently attempting to do this in an SDK. Authentec is one, but even in there SDK it is not possible to shut off the VPN connection yet. I came here looking to see if anyone has done this before but I know it is not possible through Java code, it will have to be in Native Code ( C for simpletons like myself)